# Don't understand ATmega32 timer delay program

Tags: c, microcontroller, avr, atmega

i have the following program...

"Write a program to toggle all the bits of PORTB continuously with some delay. Use Timer0, Normal mode, and no prescaler option."

```
#include….
    void T0Delay()
    int main ()
    DDRB= 0xFF;
    while (1) {
        PORTB=0x55;
        T0Delay();
        PORTB=0xAA;
        T0Delay();
    }

void T0Delay ()
    {
        TCNT0=0x20;
        TCCR0=0x01;
        while ((TIFR&01)==0);
        TCCR0=0;
        TIFR=0x01;
    }
```

In the "TODelay()" function, what is function of "while ((TIFR&01)==0)" statment? And why is this loop setting TCCR0=0 and TIFR=0x01?
Can anyone explain this piece of code, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statement `while ((TIFR&01)==0);` is the entire loop. The two statements that follow are not part of this loop, and are executed after the loop has finished.

The purpose of this loop is to wait until the least significant bit of `TIFR` is set. Presumably this is declared somewhere as a volatile integer, and is mapped to the address of a control input port (otherwise this loop will never terminate).

Comment: Correct, TIFR is the "timer interrupt flag register". The respective flag will be set to 1 once the timer expired. AVR Interrupt flags are cleared (set to 0) by writing a 1 to the register. Thts what `TIFR=0x01` is for.

Answer (score 2):

`while ((TIFR&01)==0);` is a busy-waiting loop. It continues to loop until the flag indicating the timer has expired changes to 1. Only then does the flow exit the loop.

`TIFR=0x01;` is a peculiar instruction. It actually clears the flag; that is, it sets the flag to `0` and not `1` as you might expect.

So the delay function sets the timer count, starts the timer, then busy waits in a loop until the timer reaches the end. After that it clears the timer flag to allow the timer to be used again.

Answer (score 0):

Check the whole line with the loop, don't it end with a semicolon? That means the loop body is an empty statement, and that it for the loop.

The assignments are not part of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop keeps checking and waiting for the timer to overflow, once the timer overflows, it sets the timer again, and returns